# getting the value of a code-mirror element

Tags: polymer, codemirror

I am using the code-mirror component from the Polymer Designer, and can set the initial value, but cannot see how to get changes to the code from the user.

I initialise the code-mirror using

```
<code-mirror id="code_mirror" value="{{code}}">


</code-mirror>
```

and would like to listen for changes in {{code}}, but codeChanged doesn't seem to fire.

I know I can get the actual value using code_mirror.$.mirror.getValue(), but would like to use data-binding.

I have tried using on-change to no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're using https://github.com/PolymerLabs/code-mirror what you need to do is make the `CodeMirror` instance created in the `ready` handle some events that the instance itself is emitting, then make the `code-mirror` element fire [any custom event](https://www.polymer-project.org/docs/polymer/polymer.html#fire) (something which I know is called *event relay*)

The following example makes the polymer element fire the custom event `code-change` whenever the editor value is changed

```
ready: function() {
    var me = this;
    //...

    this.mirror = CodeMirror(this.shadowRoot, { /* ... */ });

    this.mirror.on('change', function () {
        // me = polymer instance
        me.fire('code-change', { value: me.mirror.getValue() })
    });
}
```

Then any instance of the polymer custom element would need to listen to that event using Polymer's declarative event mapping or through `addEventListener`

1st case (if `code-mirror` is inside another `<polymer-element />`):

```
<code-mirror on-code-change="{{ onCodeChange }}"></code-mirror>
// ...
<script>
Polymer({
  onCodeChange: function(event, detail, sender) { ... }
});
</script>
```

2nd case ():

```
<code-mirror></code-mirror>
<script>
   document
       .querySelector('code-mirror')
       .addEventListener('code-change', function () { ... });
</script>
```